# kinesis producer "merges" messages

Tags: java, stream, amazon-kinesis

I'm using a kinesis producer in a component test. When I run the kinesis producer on debug mode and break before I insert the data to the stream, so there is time between each push, everything works fine. But when I run it without any breaks (or not in debug mode) something happens and when I read the data in the kinesis consumer I see one message less and one message double the size as if two messages merged into one, that message throws an exception when I try to deserialize it

```
    private AmazonKinesis getClient() {
    if(client != null) {
        return client;
    }

    System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking", "true");
    AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
            configuration.getKinesisEndpoint(), awsCredentialsConf.getRegion());

    try {
        client = AmazonKinesisClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
                .build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error reading message from Kafka: ", ex);
    }
    return client;
}

public List<Record> readMessage() {
    try {
        AmazonKinesis client = getClient();

        DescribeStreamResult data = client.describeStream(configuration.getConsumerStreamName());
        List<Shard> shards = data.getStreamDescription().getShards();
        Shard shId = shards.get(0);

        GetShardIteratorRequest iteratorRequest = new GetShardIteratorRequest();
        iteratorRequest.setStreamName(configuration.getConsumerStreamName());
        iteratorRequest.setShardId(shId.getShardId());

        iteratorRequest.setShardIteratorType("TRIM_HORIZON");
        GetShardIteratorResult iteratorResponse = client.getShardIterator(iteratorRequest);
        String iterator = iteratorResponse.getShardIterator();

        GetRecordsRequest getRequest = new GetRecordsRequest();
        getRequest.setLimit(1000);

        getRequest.setShardIterator(iterator);

        Thread.sleep(SECONDS.toMillis(3));
        // call "get" operation and get everything in this shard range
        GetRecordsResult getResponse = client.getRecords(getRequest);
        return getResponse.getRecords();

    } catch(Exception rnfe) {
        log.error("Failed to communicate with stream " + configuration.getConsumerStreamName(), rnfe);
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}

com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:102) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:625) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.skipMessage(CodedInputStream.java:723) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:655) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.platform.protobuf.messages.rawstream.ProtobufStreamEventHeader$ProtobufStreamEvent.<init>(ProtobufStreamEventHeader.java:92) ~[protobuf-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.platform.protobuf.messages.rawstream.ProtobufStreamEventHeader$ProtobufStreamEvent.<init>(ProtobufStreamEventHeader.java:57) ~[protobuf-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.platform.protobuf.messages.rawstream.ProtobufStreamEventHeader$ProtobufStreamEvent$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtobufStreamEventHeader.java:811) ~[protobuf-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.platform.protobuf.messages.rawstream.ProtobufStreamEventHeader$ProtobufStreamEvent$1.parsePartialFrom(ProtobufStreamEventHeader.java:806) ~[protobuf-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:158) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:191) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:203) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:208) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48) ~[protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.platform.protobuf.messages.rawstream.ProtobufStreamEventHeader$ProtobufStreamEvent.parseFrom(ProtobufStreamEventHeader.java:334) ~[protobuf-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.platform.streaming.impl.ProtoStreamEventHeader.deserialize(ProtoStreamEventHeader.java:43) ~[streaming-common-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.platform.streaming.impl.StreamProtobufSerializer.deserialize(StreamProtobufSerializer.java:41) ~[streaming-common-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.panpwr.collector.CollectorSteps.lambda$retrieveDataFromStream$2(CollectorSteps.java:414) [main/:na]
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at com.panpwr.collector.CollectorSteps.retrieveDataFromStream(CollectorSteps.java:413) [main/:na]
at com.panpwr.collector.CollectorSteps.readMessages(CollectorSteps.java:366) [main/:na]
at com.panpwr.collector.CollectorSteps.checkErrorCorrection(CollectorSteps.java:330) [main/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:49) ~[cucumber-java-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:63) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:49) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:44) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:40) ~[cucumber-core-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:146) ~[cucumber-junit-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68) ~[cucumber-junit-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23) ~[cucumber-junit-4.2.0.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73) ~[cucumber-junit-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:124) ~[cucumber-junit-4.2.0.jar:na]
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:65) ~[cucumber-junit-4.2.0.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:133) ~[cucumber-junit-4.2.0.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
```

Comment: Show us your code, error message, etc.

Comment: added code and stacktrace, thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the source code of record deserializer ? From the stack trace it seems that the protobuf is used - if yes, then it makes sense to use `parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream)` method instead of `parseFrom`